# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect due to object can not be resolved

Tags: json, spring-mvc, post

I build a springmvc POST rest API. And it will accept a posted object "Test". But when I submit a post request via postman. I get errors:

```
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 - </h1>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>
        <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>message</b>
        <u></u>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>description</b>
        <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u>
    </p>
    <hr class="line">
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.35</h3>
</body>
```

Seems the controller can not convert the json data to the object. Anyone knows why the controller can't convert it?

Here's my method handling the post request in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =   "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Test test(@RequestBody Test user) {

    System.out.println(user.toString());
    return user;

}
```

Here's the POST request's json data:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "age": 0,
    "name": "user",
    "address": null,
    "email": null
  }
}
```

Here's the object "Test":

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7788619177798333712L;
    private String name;
    private User user;

    public Test( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Test( String name, User user ) {
        this( name );
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUser( User user ) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "[ " );
        sb.append( "name: " ).append(this.name).append( ", " );
        sb.append( user.toString() ).append( " ]" );

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And the field user is an instance of class User.

---

### EDITED for UPDATE

I used to miss default constructor in my "Test" class. After adding a default constructor to the class. The issue got resolved. But I'm not sure why the default constructor matters. Anyone can help on this?

Comment: did you specify content-type in postman

Comment: @VikramSingh yes, content-type is "application/json".

Comment: I used to miss default constructor in my "Test" class. After adding a default constructor to the class. The issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC by default configures beans with a no-args cstor and setters. You need to manually change your beans.xml to configure beans via args cstors.